# Retreive all records from external dictionary in clickhouse

Tags: mongodb, clickhouse

I have added MongoDB as external dictionary, I can retrieve data from mongodb using the below query.

```
select dictGetString('table', 'field', tuple(toUInt16(4089))) columnName
```

How to retrieve all records from external dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a specific database to retrieve data from all dictionaries.

```
CREATE DATABASE dictionaries ENGINE = Dictionary;
SELECT * FROM dictionaries.<your dictionary name>;
```

Comment: The question is, how to get all fields at once instead of reusing `dictGetString` and `dictGetUInt64` again and again.

Comment: @SarthakSawhney Isn't this answer for that specific purpose?

Comment: your query will list out all the dictionaries, he needs all the columns pushed to one of the dictionary he made. When using `dictGetString` in a select operation as a field. If I have one key named `id` and `v1`, `v2`, `v3` as three values, i have to write `dictGet` thrice to fetch each value associated with `id`. I hope I made my case clearer.

Comment: No. The query will do exactly what you want. If you want to list all dictionaries, actually you need `show tables from dictionaries`